# What is the way to know where a html element's height comes from? (using Chrome dev tools)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Context**

Normally I use Chrome dev tools to see an element's (computed) style attributes, and their location in .css. However now I see that an element's height is grayed out. So I am supposing this is given implicitly from element's parent.

Unfortunately when inspecting its parent, still height grayed out... and so on.

**Question**

What is the correct and fast way to find the .css line where a given rendered element's computed is height coming from?

Comment: Isn't the height of the element calculated dynamically by the children in the element so that all are visible? I don't think there is a height declared if it's grayed out.

Comment: This was the leaf level child. so no. Meanwhile I found out there was a min-height and max height declared as 120px... I will delete this question soon, Anyway thanks.